# How to make a loop to reuse a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with multiple buttons that add a class for 300 ms. Right now if I press any of those buttons all the buttons receive the class at the same time. I need that by pressing each voice only he receives the class, not the rest of the buttons.

How to make a loop to reuse a function? 
I think my problem is that I do not know how to `loop` my function "update" and that I only select the button I pressed and add the class in that same "div"

**I edit my code with @josemartindev changes:**

```
class Telefono extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, '*', 0, '#'],
            letters: ['', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqrs', 'tuv', 'wxyz', '', '', ''],
            addClicked: [],
            numberClicked: '',
        };
    }

    update(number) {
        console.log("You clicked number " + number);
        let v = []
        for (var i = 0; i < this.props.addClicked.length; i++)
        {
            if (number === i)
                this.setState({
                    addClicked: "clicked"
                });
            else
                this.setState({
                    addClicked: []
                });
        }

        this.setState({
            addClicked: v
        })

        this.change = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                addClicked: []
                })
        }, 300)

        console.log(v)

    }

    render(){
        return(            
            <div className="pad sb-content">
                <div className="dial-pad">
                    <div className="phoneString">
                        <input type="text"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="digits">
                    <Numbers 
                        numbers={this.state.numbers} 
                        letters={this.state.letters}
                        addClicked={this.props.addClicked}  
                        update={this.update}
                    />
                    </div>

                    <div className="digits">
                        <div id="nuevo-contacto"><Icon id="nuevo-contacto" icon="nuevo-usuario" className='dig addPerson action-dig ico-nuevo-usuario'/></div>
                        <div className="dig goBack action-dig"><Icon icon="borrar" className='ico-borrar'/></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="call-pad">
                    <div id="ca-number" className="ca-number">1234567890</div>
                    <div className="ca-status" data-dots="...">Llamando</div>
                    <div className="ca-buttons">
                        <div id="mute" className="ca-b-single" data-label="Mute"><a><Icon icon="audio" className='ico-audio'/><Icon icon="mute" className='ico-mute'/></a></div>
                        <div id="hold" className="ca-b-single" data-label="Hold"><a><Icon icon="musica" className='ico-musica'/></a></div>
                        <div id="transferir" className="ca-b-single" data-label="Transferir"><a><Icon icon="transferir" className='ico-transferir'/></a></div>
                        <div id="keypad" className="ca-b-single" data-label="Teclado"><a><Icon icon="keypad" className='ico-keypad'/></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="call action-dig">
                    <div className="call-change"><span></span></div>
                    <div className="call-icon"><Icon icon="telefono" className='ico-telefono'/></div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        );
    }
}

class Numbers extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>            
                <div className={"dig pound number-dig "+ this.props.addClicked} onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "1")}>{this.props.numbers[0]}<div class="sub-dig">{this.props.letters[0]}</div></div>
                <div className={"dig pound number-dig "+ this.props.addClicked} onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "2")}>{this.props.numbers[1]}<div class="sub-dig">{this.props.letters[2]}</div></div>
                <div className={"dig pound number-dig "+ this.props.addClicked} onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "3")}>{this.props.numbers[2]}<div class="sub-dig">{this.props.letters[2]}</div></div>
                <div className={"dig pound number-dig "+ this.props.addClicked} onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "4")}>{this.props.numbers[3]}<div class="sub-dig">{this.props.letters[3]}</div></div>
                <div className={"dig pound number-dig "+ this.props.addClicked} onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "5")}>{this.props.numbers[4]}<div class="sub-dig">{this.props.letters[4]}</div></div>
                <div className={"dig pound number-dig "+ this.props.addClicked} onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "6")}>{this.props.numbers[5]}<div class="sub-dig">{this.props.letters[5]}</div></div>
                <div className={"dig pound number-dig "+ this.props.addClicked} onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "7")}>{this.props.numbers[6]}<div class="sub-dig">{this.props.letters[6]}</div></div>
                <div className={"dig pound number-dig "+ this.props.addClicked} onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "8")}>{this.props.numbers[7]}<div class="sub-dig">{this.props.letters[7]}</div></div>
                <div className={"dig pound number-dig "+ this.props.addClicked} onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "9")}>{this.props.numbers[8]}<div class="sub-dig">{this.props.letters[8]}</div></div>
                <div className={"dig pound number-dig "+ this.props.addClicked} onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "10")}>{this.props.numbers[9]}<div class="sub-dig">{this.props.letters[9]}</div></div>
                <div className={"dig pound number-dig "+ this.props.addClicked} onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "11")}>{this.props.numbers[10]}<div class="sub-dig">{this.props.letters[10]}</div></div>
                <div className={"dig pound number-dig "+ this.props.addClicked} onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "12")}>{this.props.numbers[11]}<div class="sub-dig">{this.props.letters[11]}</div></div>
        </>
        );
    }
}
```

In addtion function that I wanted to reuse is `updat` and the `addclicked` status is not applied to any of the elements ...

I need the update function to add the class only to the button that was pressed, does anyone know how to do that? As it is now it does not work for me

**Explanation changes button**

When I click on the 5 I need to add the "clicked" class in the dig "dig pound number-dig" and it will disappear at the moment because it is a zoom effect. My code

```
this.change = setTimeout (() => {
      this.setState ({
          addClicked: []
      })
}, 300)
```

should do it. Clicked should only be added to the button that clicked and then disappear, should not be added on all buttons. I can not pass the class, although at the beginning before these changes if it worked and I clicked all the elements (and I wanted it to be only on a button). It's a kind of toggle effect that by pressing any button the class is added only in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? Check my demo below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, '*', 0, '#'],
      letters: ['', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqrs', 'tuv', 'wxyz', '', '', ''],
      numberClicked: [],
      addClicked: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount()
  {
    const v = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
      v.push("notClicked")
    this.setState({
      addClicked: v
    })
    //console.log(v)
  }

  update = (number) => {
    const n = [...this.state.numberClicked]
    const c = [...this.state.addClicked]
    c[number - 1] = 'clicked'
    console.log(c)
    n.push(number)
    this.setState({
      numberClicked: n,
      addClicked: c 
    }, () => {
        let a = "";
        for (var i in this.state.numberClicked)
        {
          a = a + this.state.numberClicked[i] + " "
        }
        console.log("All Values: ", a)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Numbers numbers={this.state.numbers} letters={this.state.letters} update={this.update}/>
    );
  }
}

class Numbers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="parent-wrapper">
        <div className="parent">
            <div className="child" onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "1")}><h1>{this.props.numbers[0]}</h1><p>{this.props.letters[0]}</p></div>
            <div className="child" onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "2")}><h1>{this.props.numbers[1]}</h1><p style={{marginLeft: "16px"}}>{this.props.letters[1]}</p></div>
            <div className="child" onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "3")}><h1>{this.props.numbers[2]}</h1><p style={{marginLeft: "17px"}}>{this.props.letters[2]}</p></div>
            <div className="child" onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "4")}><h1>{this.props.numbers[3]}</h1><p style={{marginLeft: "17px"}}>{this.props.letters[3]}</p></div>
            <div className="child" onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "5")}><h1>{this.props.numbers[4]}</h1><p style={{marginLeft: "20px"}}>{this.props.letters[4]}</p></div>
            <div className="child" onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "6")}><h1>{this.props.numbers[5]}</h1><p style={{marginLeft: "14px"}}>{this.props.letters[5]}</p></div>
            <div className="child" onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "7")}><h1>{this.props.numbers[6]}</h1><p style={{marginLeft: "13px"}}>{this.props.letters[6]}</p></div>
            <div className="child" onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "8")}><h1>{this.props.numbers[7]}</h1><p style={{marginLeft: "17px"}}>{this.props.letters[7]}</p></div>
            <div className="child" onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "9")}><h1>{this.props.numbers[8]}</h1><p style={{marginLeft: "12px"}}>{this.props.letters[8]}</p></div>
            <div className="child" onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "10")}><h1>{this.props.numbers[9]}</h1><p>{this.props.letters[9]}</p></div>
            <div className="child" onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "11")}><h1>{this.props.numbers[10]}</h1><p>{this.props.letters[10]}</p></div>
            <div className="child" onClick={this.props.update.bind(this, "12")}><h1>{this.props.numbers[11]}</h1><p>{this.props.letters[11]}</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rnzxye)

Comment: Hi. I tried to use your code but it did not work out very well. I have updated my code to see if you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: @Casandra do you want to know for example: If I press 5 and 6, to have the numbers 5, 6 in memory (in a string for example) to use them later? I can help you with that

Comment: Yes, that's the next thing I wanted to do.

Comment: I updated my demo @Cassandra. Open the console below and click on numbers. I created a class Numbers, since they will always be the same.

Comment: your changes are perfect for me, but i still have the initial problem, I can not get the update function to add the "clicked" class when I click on a button

Comment: Ok, that's another issue. Could you give me an example to understand better? If you click 5 and 6, you want to change the class, so If you want to change the class I imagine you want to change the style of the button?

Comment: I think I understood your problem, let me see if I can modify my answer.

Comment: @Casandra I modified my answer and now it should work. Check the console again, I think everything is like you want it

Comment: Thanks again, i'ts really perfect. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Cool! No problem :)